# Recommended placement for Add AND Edit buttons when both a navigation controller and tab bar controller are present

Tags: ios, user-interface, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I'm building an app which contains a few scenes that need both an add ("+" button) function and an edit ("Edit" button) function.

Each of these scenes displays a table view which is embedded in a navigation controller – so the top-left spot on the navigation bar is occupied. The app also uses a tab bar controller which makes me hesitant to use a bottom toolbar for one of the buttons.

After skimming the [iOS HIG](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/) I'm not certain of the recommended layout to get both the "+" and "Edit" buttons on the screen given these constraints. Here are a few options I've considered.

1. I can put "Edit" in the top-right and put the "+" button in a cell in the table view. I think an older version of the Hanging with Friends app did this. However, this isn't done in any of Apple's apps and I didn't see it in the HIG.
2. I can add a toolbar to the bottom and put one of the buttons there and the other in the top-right navigation bar spot, but the same concern applies. I haven't seen any apps do this and I didn't see anything in the HIG about combining the toolbar with the tab bar controller (it works above the tab bar but adds a lot of buttons to the bottom of a screen).
3. I can make a top-right button that opens a modal popup window, freeing up two spots (left and right of that navigation bar) to add the buttons. The native Stocks app does this. Unfortunately, the "+" function I need also works best in a modal popup and that one leads to another table view containing an option for a second modal popup in the form of a standard contact controller. Three modal popups is not recommended in the HIG.
4. I've seen other questions and answers on stackexchange about how to put two buttons on the right of the navigation bar, but the HIG recommends against that.

*What is the recommended way (must be compatible with the HIG) to add this functionality given these constraints, and why?* Can you cite sources or example apps? I appreciate any thoughts or recommendations anyone might be willing to share. :)

Comment: This question may be better suited for http://ux.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thank you, rmaddy. I'll look there.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to replace the back button with the add button while being in editing mode.

This can be accomplished by overriding `setEditing:` for example in Swift:

```
override func setEditing(editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
  super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
  if editing {
    let addButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem:.Add, target:self, action:"addAction:")
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = addButton
  } else {
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, vadian. I have reservations taking this approach because it doesn't make the "+" button (add function) very intuitive since it's hidden until the Edit button is tapped. I also haven't seen this used in any of Apple's apps (or any other apps) and haven't seen a reference to it in the HIG. Please let me know if you have. I will consider it further though. Either way, it may be a good solution for someone else. I think I'll take rmaddy's advice and check out the ux.stackexchange.com site.